# Spring Framework: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring

While running script in Spring framework it is throwing error message as "Failed to load ApplicationContext". I have my ApplicationContext.xml file under src/test/resources
And i was using

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class CustomerTest extends FunctionLibrary { ... }
```

After some suggestions from forum i used

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/test/resources/applicationContext.xml")
public class CustomerTest extends FunctionLibrary { ... }
```

Still i am getting the same error message. Please anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Sudhansu

Comment: You typically resolve issues by first reading the exception stack trace.

Comment: For starters you'll need to drop @RunWith(Parameterized.class) and replace it with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) (this means that your JUnit test will not be parameterized and you will need to find some other way to you the parameterized feature)

Comment: After replacing @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) with @RunWith(Parameterized.class)..It is showing error message like class<SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class> cant resolved to type..How to reslove this error message?

Comment: Do you have the spring-test dependency on your classpath?

Comment: yes... <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: did you missed the import statement?

Comment: no..I have imported import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

Comment: It is showing initialization error

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems

1)  use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

2) Your path sounds like you have a maven project. In a maven project, `src/test/resources` will be added to the classpath when the tests run. So use:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

*If you haven an other file in `src/main/resources` withe the same name, then I recommend to rename the one in `src/test/resources` to `test-applicationContext.xml` and then use `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml")`,  just to reduce the the number of knot in your brain*

Complete example:

```
package com.test.service;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classpath:test-ApplicationContext.xml)
public class WhateverTest {
...
}
```

pom excerpt:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I have added these two annotations @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml") but it is showing Junit Initialization errors...How to fix the initialization errors..I think not able to find the path of the applicatioContext.xml file

Comment: @user3411418: You need to post the initializing errors - I can't guess them.

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:147)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)

Comment: @user3411418: really? start reading the exception! "Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor"

Comment: I have one parameterized constructor public CustomerTest(Config config) throws Exception {
  super(config);
  /
 }

Comment: user3411418: A "zero-argument" controller is required! Zero mean no parameter (Btw: This has noting to do with spring, this are JUnit basic rules).